# Scraping data in to a dataframe

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

Is there an elegant way to scrape data from URLs such as below directly into a dataframe?:

https://israeldrugs.health.gov.il/#!/medDetails/145%2020%2032014%2000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://israeldrugs.health.gov.il/#!/medDetails/145 20 32014 00"
api_url = (
    "https://israeldrugs.health.gov.il/GovServiceList/IDRServer/GetSpecificDrug"
)
drug_id = url.split("/")[-1]

data = requests.post(api_url, json={"dragRegNum": drug_id}).json()

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        dragRegNum      dragHebName   bitulDate  isCytotoxic  isVeterinary applicationType                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         brochure brochureUpdate  isPrescription  iscanceled                                                             images       dragEnName usageFormHeb usageFormEng            dosageForm           dosageFormEng                                                                                                                                                                                                  dragIndication  maxPrice  health                                             activeMetirals                         regOwnerName                         regManufactureName       regDate    regExpDate  applicationDate custom                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 manufacturers limitations dateOfInclusion indicationIncludedInTheBasket classEffect remarks packingLimitation registeredIndicationsAtTimeOfInclusion frameworkOfInclusion useInClalit salList                                                                                                                                                atc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           packages videos
0  145 20 32014 00  אדויל פורטה 400  01/01/1900        False         False      תכשיר גנרי  [{'lng': None, 'url': 'Rishum_17_463219520.pdf', 'updateDate': 1607238596000.0, 'type': 'החמרה לעלון', 'display': 'החמרה לעלון', 'updateDateFormat': '06.12.2020', 'creationDateFormat': '25.11.2020'}, {'lng': None, 'url': 'Rishum_20_510626721.pdf', 'updateDate': 1624563325000.0, 'type': 'החמרה לעלון', 'display': 'החמרה לעלון', 'updateDateFormat': '24.06.2021', 'creationDateFormat': '14.06.2021'}, {'lng': 'אנגלית', 'url': 'Rishum_19_248052021.pdf', 'updateDate': 1613923027000.0, 'type': 'עלון לצרכן', 'display': 'עלון לצרכן אנגלית', 'updateDateFormat': '21.02.2021', 'creationDateFormat': '13.01.2021'}, {'lng': 'עברית', 'url': 'Rishum_20_510625821.pdf', 'updateDate': 1624563286000.0, 'type': 'עלון לצרכן', 'display': 'עלון לצרכן עברית', 'updateDateFormat': '24.06.2021', 'creationDateFormat': '14.06.2021'}, {'lng': 'ערבית', 'url': 'Rishum_19_248050821.pdf', 'updateDate': 1613922982000.0, 'type': 'עלון לצרכן', 'display': 'עלון לצרכן ערבית', 'updateDateFormat': '21.02.2021', 'creationDateFormat': '13.01.2021'}, {'lng': None, 'url': 'Rishum_20_510583121.pdf', 'updateDate': 1624560223000.0, 'type': 'עלון לרופא', 'display': 'עלון לרופא', 'updateDateFormat': '24.06.2021', 'creationDateFormat': '14.06.2021'}]           None           False       False  [{'url': 'Rishum_1_88158316.jpg', 'updateDate': 1469069874000.0}]  ADVIL FORTE 400         פומי       PER OS  קפסולות ממולאות נוזל  CAPSULES LIQUID FILLED  Relief of mild to moderate pain such as headache, treatment of pain associated with migraine  toothache, menstrual pain, backache, muscular pain, anti-inflammatory for rheumatic disease, reduction of fever.      49.2   False  [{'ingredientsDesc': 'IBUPROFEN', 'dosage': '400   MG '}]  GSK CONSUMER HEALTHCARE, ISRAEL LTD  PFIZER CONSUMER MANUFACTURING ITALY S.R.L  1.454198e+12  1.769818e+12     1.233619e+12         [{'manufactureName': 'CATALENT ARGENTINA SAIC', 'manufactureSite': 'AVENIDA BERNABE MARQUEZ 691 B1657CSA - VILLA LOMA HERMOSA, BUENOS AIRES, ARGENTINA', 'manufactureComments': 'bulk   '}, {'manufactureName': 'PFIZER CONSUMER MANUFACTURING ITALY S.R.L.', 'manufactureSite': 'VIA NETTUNENSE 90, APRILILA, ITALY', 'manufactureComments': 'release , testing , labelling , packaging '}]        None            None                          None        None    None              None                                   None                 None        None      []  [{'atc4Code': 'M02AA', 'atc4Name': 'ANTIINFLAMMATORY PREPARATIONS, NON STEROID FOR TOPICAL USE', 'atc5Code': 'M02AA13', 'atc5Name': 'IBUPROFEN'}]  [{'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '96 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '100 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '4 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '6 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '8 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '10 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '12 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '16 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '2.46', 'packageMaxPrice': '49.2', 'quantity': '20 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': '7290012368332'}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '24 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '30 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '32 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '36 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '48 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '50 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}, {'isPrescription': True, 'packageUpdate': 0.0, 'packageDesc': 'BLISTER PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'packMaterialDesc': 'PVC/PE/PVDC/AL', 'unitPrice': '0', 'packageMaxPrice': '0', 'quantity': '60 CAPSULES', 'shelfLife': '36', 'unit': 'חדשים', 'barcode': ''}]     []
```

Comment: Thanks!! Can you explain how did you find the api_url?

Comment: @gtomer When you open Firefox Developer Tools -> Network Tab (chrome has something similar) you will see all requests the page is doing. One of the request is this Json call.

Comment: However, this gives only part of the data. e.g. it did not give the data: "GSK CONSUMER HEALTHCARE". Can you help?

Comment: @gtomer `GSK CONSUMER HEALTHCARE, ISRAEL LTD` is in column `regOwnerName` of the dataframe.

Comment: Missed that. Sorry. Thanks!!